# Nextjs keep redirecting with double locale

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization

We trying to redirect client if client's wish locale is not provided in the page.

So i added

```
    redirect: !isPossibleLang
      ? {
          destination: `/${locale}/main/${id}`,
          statusCode: 301,
        }
      : undefined,
```

In the return of getStaticProps.

But next.js keep adding current language in the url.
like `/ko/main/ID` => `/en/ko/main/ID`

My next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'ko'],
    defaultLocale: 'ko',
  },
  ...
};
```

How to stop redirect with double locale ?

Comment: Can you please provide the full code for the `getStaticProps` function?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to include more code in the question, without giving readers undefined variables or without context. To help us better understand the problem and help you.

In my opinion you are passing unnecessarily the `locale` variable in the template string.

Maybe this is better like a comment but have no allow to comment yet.